# camera not working properly

Tags: modeling, rendering

[image]
when i press number pad 0 or select the camera it doesn't work .. it only select the plane and when i press number pad 0 again it just zoom in to the donut i restored shortcuts to it's default and that didn't help
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you unintentionally set a different object as the Camera (a plane in your case), you can reset it back to camera by either selecting your camera as the Camera in the Scene Properties tab, or you can select the camera and select `View > Cameras > Set Active Object as Camera`.

[image: Camera]

You also may want to disable your view locks:

[image: ViewLock]